# Remove commands from php artisan list

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to remove some commands from the `php artisan list`?

I find that it is too long and often I have to scroll or do grepping.  For example, some project I don't use queue and hiding the queue commands will be useful.

Comment: Another good use for hiding some commands is that many have no meaning in a production environment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just override the ArtisanServiceProvider for example:

create a new provider will name it ProductionArtisanServiceProvider

```
php artisan make:provider ProductionArtisanServiceProvider
```

Open up the new provider and change it to the following

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider as IlluminateProvider;

class ProductionArtisanServiceProvider extends IlluminateProvider
{
     protected $devCommands = [
       'AppName' => 'command.app.name',
     ];
}
```

You see above i'm overriding the $devCommands
for the full list

look inside Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider

Finally in you AppServiceProvider in the register function add your new provider and we make sure it's only loaded in the production environment

```
    if ($this->app->environment() == 'production') {
        $this->app->register(\App\Providers\ProductionArtisanServiceProvider::class);
    }
```

Now all the unnecessary commands are gone

Answer (score 2):

There's no good way to do that. Most of the core artisan commands list is stored in  the [`Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/ArtisanServiceProvider.php#L44) class within the `$commands` property. Some are registered directly from their respective service providers, like the Queue ones in `Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider`. So in theory you could comment them out there, but you **should't be making any changes** in the `vendor` directory in the first place, because they can be undone on any update.

If you find yourself having to check the command list too often, you would be better off taking a little time to commit to memory at least the commands you use on a regular basis, because it would make your workflow **far** more efficient.

---

If by any chance you're using [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/) with [Oh My Zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), then you could use the included [`laravel5`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/laravel5/laravel5.plugin.zsh) plugin which offers autocomplete in your terminal, for all registered Laravel commands. Just write `php artisan` and press TAB for an autocomplete list of the commands, no scrolling required :).

Answer (score 1):

As updated by Bogdan, there is no good way to remove command from artisan list. One option available is to override the existing command with new command with same `$signature.`

Answer (score 1):

If all the commands you are interested in start with the same prefix, for example `prefix:`, you can list them using `artisan list prefix`.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer (Steven's) is a good and clean way to remove the dev commands from the list, which certainly helps a lot, but doesn't clear everything. For example, you are still left with 'inspiration', 'make:migration', etc commands and any additional packages that you might have installed, would have probably added one or two more items in the list.

If your case is like mine and you would simply like to hide the commands from the list (but not disable them entirely), then there is an extremely simple solution:

Create a new command with a 'list' signature. E.g:

```
/**
  * The name and signature of the console command.
  *
  * @var string
  */
protected $signature = 'list';
```

Since it will be the last one registered, it will be executed when the framework calls the 'list' command. Inside the command handle, you can use:

```
$this->getApplication()->all()
```

to get the list of the registered commands. It will return an array with keys being the command names and the values the actual command objects. You can then use this to decide which to display and which to discard.

Answer (score -2):

Alight.  I finally got a good solution.  Create my own bash alias with grep.

Add this to my ~/.bashrc

All my command start with mycompany:command

Use whatever 3 letter shortcut.  `can` for me because it's the first 3 letter of my company's name.

```
alias can='php artisan | grep mycompany'
```

Comment: This isn't actually answering the question asked. Grepping the output is a work-around to only *display* certain options. It does not do the technical side of *removing* the commands  from the artisan listing.