# How to hide default artisan commands from "php artisan list" of commands?

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface, laravel-5.4, laravel-artisan

I am working on a CLI application based on Laravel 5.4.

I have created my custom commands and they are working as expected.

The issue, I am facing is, whenever I run `php artisan list`, it shows all commands - my custom commands and default artisan commands.

I need to show only my custom commands in packaged app.

Is there any way to solve this?

I have already checked https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/remove-default-commands-from-artisan and solution given there is not working for Laravel 5.4.

I have checked [Remove command from php artisan list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682276/remove-command-from-php-artisan-list) but it asks for specific commands. I want to remove all built-in commands from `php artisan list`.

**Update**

I have found a dirty way:

If I comment out line #58 from `framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php`

```
$this->bootstrap();
```

i.e. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php#L58 output is as expected.

Now I am looking for a way to stop/control `bootstrap()` function/process.

Comment: do you want to only hide the command ? or disable it?

Comment: Disable. But would like to know how to do both - together or separately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove commands from php artisan list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682276/remove-commands-from-php-artisan-list)

Comment: Hi. I know this is very old, but this question now has a correct answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682276/remove-commands-from-php-artisan-list

Answer (score 3):

To hide a command from `php artisan list` -*this will only hide the command and won't disable it*-

before going into how to hide it, let's take a look at the property `$hidden` inside the the `Illuminate\Console\Command` object , by default it's a false , when you set it to true , you will get all of your artisan list hidden.

and to hide a specific command , you will need to set this property to hidden inside each class you want to hide it's command ,

for example , when you hit `php artisan list` will prompt a list as follows :

```
.....
cache
  cache:clear          Flush the application cache
  cache:forget         Remove an item from the cache
  cache:table          Create a migration for the cache database table
.....
```

this means that , the object which is responsible about `clearing the cache` is located into `Illuminate\Cache\Console`.

now to hide the cache:clear command , inside Illuminate\Cache\Console you will get `ClearCommand.php` object .

update it and set the property `$hidden` to true , as follows :

```
protected $hidden = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I managed to do it but in a different (hopefully) wrong way. Here is the relevant code sample - https://github.com/EasyEngine/ee4-laravel/commit/051ea3fff86550f1a35adb526ef793b030d6e4e1 . I am wondering what would be side-effect of this? I will be renaming and packaging my CLI app and don't expect or want users to run default artisan commands.

Comment: It disables commands. I guess as I am overriding bootstrap process, I am preventing other commands from registration.

Comment: you may achieve this `manually` by `return false` inside the console object to disable it, for example command `cache:clear` you can disable it by return false in the `handle` method inside the clear cache object `Illuminate\Cache\Console\ClearCommand`; and so on...

Comment: I don't know if there a good way to do this , but i will try to loop up while I return back to home

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the default commands you can override them by creating a command with the same signature then add.

```
 protected $hidden = true;
```

To the class.